# How to export Jexcel table to .csv and .xls?

Tags: export, export-to-csv, xls, jexcelapi, jexceljs

I am using Angular 8 in the application and Jexcel 3.9 plugin for the table, am new to jexcel plugin & looking to export jexcel table to .csv and .xls

I am getting materials for import into the application but couldn't found on how to export jexcel table.

I tried following but it's not working somehow

`jexcel(document.getElementById('tbl_id')).download();`

Reference : https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v2/docs/quick-reference

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it:
document.getElementById('tbl_id').jexcel.download();

Options in the most recent versions:
https://jspreadsheet.com/v7/examples/exporting-to-xls

Comment: Export xls option is free ?

Comment: Yes, it is. https://github.com/jspreadsheet/plugins/tree/master/xls